# Doctrine2 Integrity constraint violation: 1048 while inserting 2 one-to-one assications

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, persistence

Hi i get the exceptions:

```
INSERT INTO persons (contact_id, addresses_id, files_id, firstname, middlename, lastname, gender, birthday, cdate, udate, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [2, null, null, "Foo", "", "Bar", 1, null, "2014-01-10 15:59:45", null, null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'addresses_id' cannot be null
```

When i want to create a new person with new contact and address relations.

Controller:

```
// Person Contact
$contact = new Contact();
$contact->populate($contactData);
$em->persist($contact);

// Person Address
$address = new Address();
$address->populate($addressData);
$countryRef = $em->getReference('Admin\Entity\Country', $address->getCountriesId());
$address->setCountry($countryRef);
$em->persist($address);

$person = new Person();
$person->populate($personData);
$person->setContact($contact);
$person->setAddress($address);

$em->persist($person);
$em->flush();
```

Address Model:

```
class Address implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
/**
 * Instance of InputFilterInterface.
 *
 * @var InputFilter
 */
private $inputFilter;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="countries_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
protected $countriesId;

// Removed not important fields

/**
 * @var datetime
 * @ORM\Column(name="cdate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $cdate;

/**
 * @var datetime
 * @ORM\Column(name="udate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $udate;

/**
 * @var \Admin\Entity\Company
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Admin\Entity\Company", mappedBy="address")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="addresses_id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $company;

/**
 * @var \Admin\Entity\Person
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Admin\Entity\Person", mappedBy="address")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="addresses_id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $person;

/**
 * @var \Admin\Entity\Country
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Admin\Entity\Country", inversedBy="addresses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="countries_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $country;
```

Contact model:

```
class Contact implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
/**
 * Instance of InputFilterInterface.
 *
 * @var InputFilter
 */
private $inputFilter;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * Primary email address
 *
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, nullable=true, options={"comment"="Primary email address"})
 */
protected $email;


// Removed not important fields

/**
 * @var datetime
 * @ORM\Column(name="cdate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $cdate;

/**
 * @var datetime
 * @ORM\Column(name="udate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $udate;

/**
 * @var \Admin\Entity\CompaniesHasPerson
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Admin\Entity\CompaniesHasPerson", mappedBy="contact")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="contact_id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $companiesHasPerson;

/**
 * @var \Admin\Entity\Company
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Admin\Entity\Company", mappedBy="contact")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="contact_id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $company;

/**
 * @var \Admin\Entity\Person
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Admin\Entity\Person", mappedBy="contact")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="contact_id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $person;
```

And the strange fact is that when i switch the address model with the contact model and persist the address model first, doctrine will throw the error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO persons (contact_id, addresses_id, files_id, firstname, middlename, lastname, gender, birthday, cdate, udate, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, 2, null, "Foo", "", "Bar", 1, null, "2014-01-10 16:16:50", null, null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'contact_id' cannot be null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First glance: `name="id", referencedColumnName="contact_id"` are the wrong way round.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional